# Is there a way to slice a string in a new variable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, slice

I am using JavaScript for a pop up that when the user visits the web page there is a chart saying What is your name? So the user need to write his name. In just one field. If the user writes two words the program would dive the name into separate first and last name strings.

I'm using this code but is not working the slice method for the last name, it just give in the first name everything. What I am doing wrong?

```js
var fullname;
fullname = prompt("What is your name?");
fullname.indexOf(" ");

var indexOfSpace = fullname.indexOf(" ");
var firstname = "";
var lastname = "";

if (fullname.indexOf = -1) {
  firstname = fullname;
  lastname = "";
} else {
  firstname = fullname;
  lastname = fullname.slice(fullname.indexOf + 1);
}


console.log("Your visitor wrote : " + fullname + "\n\n" +
  "So his first name is: " + firstname + "\n" +
  " and" + "\n" +
  "his lastname is: " + lastname
);
alert("You wrote : " + fullname + "\n\n" +
  "So your first name is: " + firstname + "\n" +
  " and" + "\n" +
  "your lastname is: " + lastname + "!"
);
```

Comment: `if (fullname.indexOf = -1)` indexOf needs a parameter - `=` is assignment. You likely meant `if (indexOfSpace === -1)`

Comment: If this is a site people will actually use, keep in mind that given names can consist out of multiple words as well. Also some cultures put the last name first and the given name last. The code shown has syntax errors.

Comment: More issues: `firstname = fullname.slice(0,indexOfSpace);   lastname = fullname.slice(indexOfSpace+1)`

Comment: But use split instead...

Comment: how can I use split?

Comment: have a look here: [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `if (fullname.indexOf = -1)` indexOf needs a parameter - You likely meant `if (indexOfSpace === -1)`
- `=` is assignment. `==` or `===` is comparison
- `firstname = fullname.slice(0,indexOfSpace);`
- `lastname = fullname.slice(indexOfSpace+1)`

Fixed code.

```js
let fullname = prompt("What is your name?");
let firstname = "";
let lastname = "";

const indexOfSpace = fullname.indexOf(" "); // contains -1 if not found, 0 or higher if found

if (indexOfSpace === -1) {
  firstname = fullname;
  lastname = "";
} else {
  firstname = fullname.slice(0,indexOfSpace);
  lastname = fullname.slice(indexOfSpace + 1);
}


console.log("Your visitor wrote : " + fullname + "\n\n" +
  "So his first name is: " + firstname + "\n" +
  " and" + "\n" +
  "his lastname is: " + lastname
);
alert("You wrote : " + fullname + "\n\n" +
  "So your first name is: " + firstname + "\n" +
  " and" + "\n" +
  "your lastname is: " + lastname + "!"
);
```

Code using split

```js
let fullname = prompt("What is your name?");
let [firstname, lastname] = fullname.split(" "); // split using destructuring
lastname = lastname || ""; // space if undefined (falsy actually) using the OR operand

console.log("Your visitor wrote : " + fullname + "\n\n" +
  "So his first name is: " + firstname + "\n" +
  " and" + "\n" +
  "his lastname is: " + lastname
);
alert("You wrote : " + fullname + "\n\n" +
  "So your first name is: " + firstname + "\n" +
  " and" + "\n" +
  "your lastname is: " + lastname + "!"
);
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much!! I saw the error. Just to make sure I understood everything good, why did you use (indexOfSpace === -1) ?

Comment: Because that is what you wanted. You look for a space using indexOf, it returns -1 if no space was found. You stored that in the indexOfSpace  so that is what we test. PS: I added a split example

Comment: Got it!! I am new on JavaScript and I am trying to understand the logic. Thanks a lot. I saw the split method too, I really appreciate your help!